# Posso apontar para arquivos do projeto dessa maneira?

Tags: java, arquivo

Trabalhando com PHP é muito fácil montar um esquema de *path* para algum arquivo, mas em Java o esquema poderá ser diferente?

Posso apontar para um arquivo começando, por exemplo, por src `File.separator`?

Exemplo:

```
private static final String MODELS_PATH = "src" + File.separator + "models" + File.separator;
```

Posso recuperar o *path* absoluto, mas somente se minha forma de apontar para um arquivo acima estiver correta.

Exemplo:

```
File file = new File(".", MyClass.MODELS_PATH);

String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

A forma de apontar para um arquivo como em `MODELS_PATH` está correta?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você quer. Você quer que o Eclipse execute este código para saber como montar o projeto completo? Se for isto, posso te dizer que Java é uma linguagem séria que não permite as gambiarras que o PHP permite.Código da aplicação é código da aplicação, informações sobre construção do projeto é algo totalmente isolado e não faz parte do código.Mas se está falando só sobre pegar um arquivo qualquer durante a execução da sua aplicação, aí o caminho é mais ou menos este.Esclareça isto pra mim e eu tentarei responder.Você poderia mostrar como faria em PHP para dar mais contexto.

Comment: @bigown Eclipse é apenas uma IDE, nunca penso em fazer qualquer coisa para ele e sim para um tempo de execução. Saber como este lida com o path de arquivos é minha principal preocupação. A única coisa que quero é aprender como apontar corretamente para um arquivo, obrigada.

Comment: Se a pergunta não está relacionada com o IDE, não deveria mencioná-lo.

Comment: @bigown Mencionei porque foi o Eclipse quem criou o sistema de pastas do projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File path = new File("src", "models");
        System.out.println(path.getPath());
        System.out.println(path.getAbsolutePath());
        File novoPath = new File(".", path.getPath());
        System.out.println(novoPath.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(novoPath.getPath());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/m3Iw8g). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qfvxqgem-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/PathBuilder.java).

Comment: Obrigada pelo exemplo, isso muda o jogo!